# How can I remove the margin and the lines between the bars of a matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have written the following code that puts bar charts and line charts into one graph. However, the data inside is not consistent, such that some data of months are missing.

How do I remove the margin between the months and remove the lines since they should not exist?

```
plt.figure(figsize=(30,10))
plt.bar(date_all, value_all, color='black',width=1)
plt.plot(date_economic_inflation, value_economic_inflation, color='r', label='Economic Inflation')
plt.plot(date_economic_cost_of_living, value_economic_cost_of_living, color='g', label='Cost of Living')
plt.plot(date_economic_income, value_economic_income, color='b', label='Income Level')
plt.plot(date_economic_redundancy, value_economic_redundancy, color='c', label='Redundancy')
plt.plot(date_economic_new_car, value_economic_new_car, color='m', label='New Car Type')
plt.plot(date_economic_policy_war, value_economic_policy_war, color='y', label='Influence of Policies & War')
xtick = np.linspace(0,10,1)
plt.xticks(fontsize=20)
plt.title('The number of tweets related to car purchase during coivd from 2019 to 2021',fontsize=18)
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Somehow your data is not being interpreted with the correct dates or is missing those dates.   There are ways to parse the dates in pandas.   However we can’t specifically help without knowing what the data set looks like